# How to connect a mini camera to four 3.5-5 inch TFT/LCD screens?

Tags: circuit-design, lcd, camera

I have an ambitious project, given my limited circuitry knowledge.

To simplify my project's potential, I want:

- One mini camera
- Four TFT/LCD displays (anywhere between 3.5 and 5 inches)
- As long as the circuit is on, that camera feeds directly to the four displays
- Nothing fancy, no Arduino, no logic, no touchscreen, no SD cards -- just relay what the camera sees to the displays
- Assume the size of this entire device to be about a box that's 5x5 base, and roughly 8-10 inches high

How do I go about doing this the CHEAPEST way possible?
Can this cost less than $100 to make?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

A camera with composite video output, and the TFT displays accepting composite video should do the trick. Those are fairly ubiquitous.

If you'd want to go the HDMI route, then the HDMI signal from the camera would need to be replicated 4 ways - one output cannot feed 4 inputs. Although that may be worth checking out - for a device of such a small size, it is imaginable that four short HDMI cables cut down to identical length, going to identical screens, all soldered to a common HDMI plug/breakout on the camera end may just happen to work. Wouldn't do that in a product, but for a one-off gizmo for fun - why not. It breaks all the HDMI rules of course, but may work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually aiming at turning this into a real product to sell, so I need to be on the right path.  If I go the composite direction, can you give me some model numbers of those modules (camera and TFT)?  I want examples to go by, because there's tons of choices out there -- I want the cheapest, but without sacrificing resolution.  The displays would be used to read text (think of a credit-card-sized kind of text, so the resolution should be just enough for such crispiness.

Comment: Anything with composite video will be equivalent. Composite video has a fixed resolution. The credit-card-sized text would need to be filling up most of the screen to be seen - think of a business card's worth of text, with a few lines squeezed into the empty space. Otherwise you'll need proper camera, SoC (CPU w/stuff) or a dedicated chip to convert whatever the camera is outputting into some panel link format, then buffers for that, and finally that going to panels accepting parallel data (not HDMI). That'd be cheapest. Development time may and would cost 100x or more than the product cost.